# using Microsoft.Identity.Client without Microsoft as identity provider, is it possible?

Tags: azure, api, openid-connect, access-token, idp

Can someone tell me if it's possible with the "Microsoft.Identity.Client" to do OpenIdConnect and get an access token which **doesn't come from Microsoft/Azure** but from another Identity Provider.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can someone tell me if it's possible with the "Microsoft.Identity.Client" to do OpenIdConnect and get an access token which doesn't come from Microsoft/Azure but from another Identity Provider

No, it's **not possible** to get an access token from third party identity provider if you are using `Microsoft.Identity.Client` with `OpenIdConnect`.

As per [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow#redeem-a-code-for-an-access-token):

- With OIDC, this flow does authentication and authorization for most app types. These types include single page apps, web apps, and natively installed apps. The flow enables apps to securely acquire an `access_token` that can be used to access resources secured by the `Microsoft identity platform`.
- All confidential clients have a choice of using client secrets or certificate credentials. Symmetric shared secrets are generated by the `Microsoft identity platform`.

You can refer to [Microsoft identity platform and OpenID Connect protocol](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-protocols-oidc), [Validating access tokens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens#validating-tokens) and [Request an access token with a client_secret](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow#request-an-access-token-with-a-client_secret)